# php array loading into javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, load

so I am a total php/javascript noob.

I'm trying load a full php array into a javascript array.
I wrote this for Javascript:

```
    var names = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
    names[i] = "<?php echo giveJS() ?>";
}
```

And this for php

```
static $counter = 0;

function giveJS() {
    global $names;
    global $counter;
    $counter++;
    return $names[$counter]; 
}
```

I already checked if the php array is correctly filled with data.
When I write a output line in javascript, like

```
document.write(names[10]);
```

it only gives me the first entry in the php array so it seems like everytime the for loop is repeated its initialising the php file from scratch and so setting the counter to 0.
How can i fix that?

Comment: Either `static $counter = 0;` (inside the function) *or* you use a global variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In php

```
//Bla being the php array you want to give to javascript. Create it however you like
$bla = array();
$bla[] = 'cat';
$bla[] = 'dog';
$bla[] = 'bat';
echo '<script>var myarray = '.json_encode($bla) .';</script>';
```

The above code will then output a script tag contain a varible called myarray, then contents of which will be JSON specifying the above array (json_encode formats the array in to javascript internal syntax- the array will probably look like ['cat','dog','bat] )

You can then get values from the JavaScript array as so:

```
<script>
 console.log(myarray[2]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP code is executed before your Javascript, thus it doesn't make sense to use it this way.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
<?php for ($i=0;$i<48;$i++):?>
     name[<?php echo $i;?>] = "<?php echo giveJS();?>";
<?php endfor; ?>
```

In fact, if your PHP is that simple, you don't need a function:

```
<?php foreach ($names as $i=>$name):?>
    name[<?php echo $i;?>] = "<?php echo $name;?>";
<?php endforeah;?>
```

In both case, you'll have a Javascript like that:

```
name[0] = 'name0';
name[1] = 'name1';
...
name[47] = 'name47';
```

Comment: You're welcome :) But, you should read other answers, they explain it better than me. And using json_encode is DEFINITELY cleaner than my solution ;) (json is a format that can be read directly by Javascript)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake for people starting web development.  The important thing to realize is that *all of your PHP code runs before the javascript starts**.  If you take a look at the javascript that gets to the browser you'll see

```
    var names = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
    names[i] = "foo";
}
```

which explains why each element is the same.  A nicer way to do this is to use json_encode in PHP to just transfer the array into a JS variable.  Like this:

`var names=<?php echo json_encode($names);?>;`

*For the people writing comments about Javascript running at the same time as the PHP, either by starting the JS early or using AJAX, yes, I'm aware, but for a beginner the model of PHP totally generates then JS starts running is simpler to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `$names[1]` is `"Bob"`..

Your PHP script will run **on the server**, *outputting* the following JavaScript:

```
var names = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
    names[i] = "Bob";
}
```

which in turn will run **in your browser** (the client), creating an array `names` with 48 `"Bob"` elements.

---

There is no easy conversation between PHP and JavaScript. Either (1) your PHP script outputs everything that the JavaScript needs to know at the outset, or (2) you communicate with the server as needed using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

In your case [JSONEncode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is probably the best solution, as it will output the array in *JavaScript Object Notation*, removing the need for loop-based initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many dimension your array have. SHortest way for simple array:

```
 var names = new Array(<?php echo implode(',', $php_array);?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `json_encode()` is what you are searching for.

Example

```
<?php
$myArray = array('generating', 'some', 'items');
?>
<script type="text/javascript>
    var myArray = <?= json_encode($myArray); ?>;
</script>
```