# Loading large values of data from php to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session, load

I read this question [php array loading into javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774126/php-array-loading-into-Javascript) to see what I can do to load a large amount of data from PHP to Javascript, it seems I may have implemented it wrong. Javascript processes and formats the data after it comes in from PHP which loads the data from a database, the data is placed into the client-side session storage so that the data can be worked with by each page. (If there is a better way to do this please let me know).

This is in one .php file.

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'classes/Membership.php';

$membership = new Membership();

$confirmation = $membership->confirm_membership();

if ($confirmation){

    $data = $membership->get_data("assump");

    echo '<script>var data = '.json_encode($data) .';</script>';

}

?>
```

This is in a separate .js file

```
function loadData(){

    // All sessionStorage can be accessed by any javascript file

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        sessionStorage.setItem("assump" + i, data[i]);

    }

}
```

However no values are being loaded. Is this even possible to do?

EDIT: I moved the javascript into the .php file where var data was being created from the php script at the top of the file, I placed the function loadData() into a script tag after the body tag in the html.

Comment: The first script is putting the data in the variable named `myarray`, the second script is looking for it in `system.assumptionValues`. You have to be consistent.

Comment: and then within the loop you are using `data[i]` instead of `system.assumptionValues[i]`

Comment: I made the edit, the values though still won't load, is this because they are in different files?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. However you may experience some problem with the scope (not 100% sure). And here is my suggestion.

Attach your variable to the window object. That's everywhere and you can access it everywhere.

```
echo '<script>window.mydata = '.json_encode($data) .';</script>';
```

Ideally you could include this line before your other scripts are included, but this should be fine. I am not sure about your session storage because I would just interact with the data directly from anywhere:

```
window.alert(window.mydata.blah...);
```

I've always found that by assigning essentially global variables, to the window object you know exactly that there are no scope problems and it's always there for you.

You can also check for it's existence using:

```
if(window.mydata!=undefined){ ... }
```

or the following but the above implies you are checking that it actually exists where as the below could not be true if window.mydata does exist but is set to false or 0 or something like that...

```
if(window.mydata){ ... }
```